# How to input elements in an array WITHOUT inputting n? (c++)

Tags: c++

> Input : 5

```
long long n;
cin>>n;
long long a[n];
for(long long i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>a[i];
}
```

How do I input elements of the array without inputting `n`?

This is what I look for :

> Input : 1,2,3,4,5

```
cout << a[0]
```

output:

> 1

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector (specifically, the example at the bottom of the page)

Comment: do u have a thought on upper limit of the array then maybe I can help you.

Comment: No, no. You don't understand. I want to *cin* the elements without *cin* the n itself.

Comment: @try using the cin as a conditional statement in the while loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard input filter loop in C++ is `while(cin >> a)` - this will read until there is no more input, or other bad things happen:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::vector<int> nums;
  while (std::cin >> a) {
    nums.push_back(a);
  }
  std::copy(nums.begin(), nums.end(), ostream_iterator<int>{cout, " "});
}
```

You could also use a one liner with input iterators - the shortest way to read elements in a vector:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> nums(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), {});
  std::copy(nums.begin(), nums.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "});
}
```

See [Ideone example here](http://ideone.com/X00ITW)

Assuming however that you wish to ignore all this C++ awesomeness, strongly discouraged IMHO, you can just:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
  int nums[MAX_SIZE]; 
  int a;
  int i=0;
  while (std::cin >> a) {
    nums[i++] = a;
  }

  // do your output
}
```

Note that you will:

1. need to guess the `MAX_SIZE`,
2. or manually handle reallocation once you read more elements than MAX_SIZE;

*Hence: use an `std::vector`!!*

Answer (score 5):

Use a `std::vector<long long> a;` instead.

Then use `long long temp;`, `cin >> temp;`, and `a.push_back(temp);`.

This means that the vector will automatically grow as you add more data. There are in a sense *smarter* ways, but my way carries the advantage of *clarity*.

These days the cool cats don't worry about repeated `push_back` as they trust a C++ standard library implementation to keep the memory nice and unfragmented for you. But if you must, then `std::vector` does allow you to set an initial *capacity* via its `reserve` method: you can still grow your vector beyond that if you wish.

Comment: I think the question is more about how do you read the elements without inputting the number beforehand, rather than how do you store them?

Comment: Yes you might be correct. Your answer is rather posh, plus one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know where the input ends. In your case, it looks like the input fits on a single line. You can read that line, construct a string stream from it, and read comma-separated items from it as follows:

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);
istringstream iss(line);
vector<long long> a;
long long tmp;
while (iss >> tmp) {
    a.push_back(tmp);
    iss.ignore(1, ',');
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/evKIPP)

Note how the above uses a `std::vector<long long>` instead of an array. This approach lets you manage storage for your data with a simple call of `push_back`, and know how much data you have entered by examining `size()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways. The most important is that if you don't know the number of values you need to use a container that can grow as needed. For that you have [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (as mention by others already).

The naive way to use a vector and read input would be something like

```
std::vector<int> vector;
while (!std::cin.eof())
{
    int value;
    std::cin >> value;
    vector.push_back(value);
}
```

[But the above loop is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)!

Using a similar approach to the above loop (but working) would be something like

```
std::vector<int> vector;
int value;
while (std::cin >> value)
{
    vector.push_back(value);
}
```

However C++ have many nice utility functions and classes that can make it even simpler.

Using the [standard algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) function [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and a few [iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) helpers ([`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)) we can write

```
std::vector<int> vector;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
          std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(vector));
```

It can, as noted by paul-g, be even simpler since there is a [vector constructor overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that takes an iterator range, so all that's really needed is

```
std::vector<int> vector(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
                        std::istream_iterator<int>());
```

Comment: Why show the wrong way to do it? Also, why use the longer istream+back_inserter when you can simply use `std::vector<int> nums(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), {});`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using of an array of pointers(More generic way to allocate array elements dynamically) :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *Arr[1000],i=0,sizeofArr=0;
    while(1){
        Arr[i] = new int;
        cin >> *Arr[i];
        if(cin.get() == '\n'){       //exit the loop if ENTER is pressed
            break;
        }
        i++;
        sizeofArr++;
    }

    for (int j=0;j<=sizeofArr;j++){
        cout << *Arr[j] <<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the worst answer of all. Do not use pointers if you don't need them. Also, the loop break condition `cin.get() == '\n'` is sloppy: what if a number is not followed directly by `\n`?